# How to resolve pipeline not triggering when merging in a Pull Request

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We are currently facing an issue in our organisation where the pipelines sometimes don't seem to trigger when merging in a Pull Request and we have to start them manually.

We have three different pipeline YAML files:

```
android-acc.yml
android-dev.yml
android-prod.yml
```

Each of these YAML files contains a trigger for a specific branch:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - 'development' # For 'android-acc' this is Acceptation. For 'android-prod' this is master
```

Due to the pipeline not triggering sometimes, I tried to configure a Trigger in the Triggers tab for the pipeline:

[image]

However, we are still facing some issues where the pipeline is sometimes not being triggered. When we manually trigger the pipeline, the pipeline runs without any issues.

What could be the issue here?

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Hi @MichielvanBeers, may i know if the trigger is working now? If it persists, you can follow the options below for a check. For the trigger for Pull request, you can also consider to use the `build validation`  in policy below as it can validate the code before your real merge.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Continuous Integration (CI)` trigger in your three yaml, but `sometimes` when merging pull request the pipeline is not triggered, it's recommended to follow below items for a check:

1. Confirm the change is really `updated` on target branch after PR merge.
2. You can `directly commit` on the branch to double confirm if the CI trigger works. If trigger is not working, editing the pipeline on `target branch` -> `remove` the CI trigger on yaml -> Save -> Add the CI trigger back, check if the trigger works.

Note: please remove UI trigger(your screenshot) when you checking
for CI yaml trigger.

3. If it doesn't work, check if there's public incident on [status](https://status.dev.azure.com/_history) page.
4. In addition, you are using DevOps git, and check with PR, you can set `branch policy` -> [build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation) on the branch to trigger the target branch.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Wade Zhou! Apologies for the delayed response, testing takes a bit of time due to PRs. 

I have applied your fixes, but unfortunately, it sometimes triggers and sometimes doesn't. I even tried recreating one of the pipelines from scratch (with only the YAML trigger). Both pipelines sometimes trigger and sometimes don't. Interestingly, it happens on the same PRs. Do you have any other ideas on how to debug this? 

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you `don't` have [batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/trigger?view=azure-pipelines#properties) option for CI yaml trigger. May i know if you removed the UI trigger as it could override the Yaml trigger. Is there any difference between the two PRs(trigger Vs not trigger)?

Comment: In addition, please also make sure the file changes are NOT excluded in [path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/trigger?view=azure-pipelines#properties). If you have `.gitignore` in the repo, make sure the files are not listed.  You are using CI yaml trigger, make sure you have completed the PR(merged).  It's recommended to commit on `same files` between two PRs to check if the issue still reproduced.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the swift answer! 
- I have validated that the batch option is turned _off_
- In the newly created pipeline, I have removed the UI trigger and only rely on the YAML trigger. This didn't fix the issue.
- There is no difference between the two triggers: both are from a PR from a feature branch to development. I paused the original pipeline and created a new pipeline based on the same YAML to see if that would fix the issue, but it didn't.
- I have validated that the files are not listed in the `.gitignore`.
What do you mean by your last remark about the same files? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @MichielvanBeers. For DevOps git repo, you can only create `one` PR between same source branch and target branch. You have to complete the existing one then you can recreate a new PR. `same files` means after you checked for 1st PR,  complete the PR, please commit on same files to create to a new PR, check if the issue persists. And what if you directly commit the branch, will it always trigger the CI pipeline as expected?

Comment: Hi, thanks again! (1) I can confirm that we only have one PR between the source (e.g. feature) and target (e.g. master) branch. (2) Committing on the same files doesn't give a different result. Sometimes it triggers, sometimes it doesn't. (3) Committing on the branch directly does trigger it as expected. (4) I've also requested budget to add the Azure DevOps support service, to see if there is something technical breaking at their side. As soon as I have a response from them, I will report back.

Comment: Thanks Michiel. If you `only have the CI trigger` as shown in your yaml, `PR merge` will work same as `direct commit` since they both use the same `CI trigger`. So it's strange that you have different appearance in (2) and (3). You can check if the CI trigger in yaml is `overwritten` after PR merge, make sure the CI trigger in yaml not changed.  To help other who have similar query, you can also post an answer in this ticket after support service resolves.

Comment: Thanks again for the additional information! I also find it a strange issue. However, I probably will not resolve this anymore, since I've come to know that our company is being acquired by another company. Therefore the focus has now shifted from migrating to the systems of the new company instead of resolving the current problems. I would like to thank you a lot for all your help, time and effort you have spent on this. I appreciate it a lot :)! Wishing you all the best.

Comment: You are welcome, wish you all the best too.